# Problema react rutas privadas y publicas

Tags: reactjs

estoy creando las rutas publicas y privadas para una app, pero el problema que me esta apareciendo es que cuando ingresa a traves de sign in, la url entra en un loop entre `localhost:3001/signin` y `localhost:3001/books/home`, haciendo el que navegador crashee.

---

Podria ser que el metodo useEffect actualice el state loggedIn provocando el problema?

---

Actualmente mi archivo routes esta configurado asi:

```
// React
import React from 'react';

// React-router-dom
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// Views
import Home from '../views/home';
import SignUp from '../views/signup';
import SignIn from '../views/signin';
import BookHome from '../views/bookviews/bookshome';

// Routes private && public
import PrivateRoute from './privateRoutes';
import PublicRoute from './publicRoutes';

class Routes extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
          <Switch>
            {/* <Route
              path="/"
              component={Home} exact/>
            <Route
              path="/signup"
              component={SignUp} />
            <Route
              path="/signin"
              component={SignIn} 
            />
            <Route
              path="/books/home"
              component={BookHome} 
            /> */}
            <PublicRoute component={Home} restricted={false} path="/" exact />
            <PublicRoute component={SignIn} restricted={true} path="/signin" exact />
            <PrivateRoute component={BookHome} path="/books/home" exact />
          </Switch>
    );
  }
}
export default Routes;
```

En mi componente PrivateRoute:

```
    // React
    import React , { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    // React-router-dom
    import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

    const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {

        const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

        useEffect(() => {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            if(token !== null) {
                setLoggedIn(true);
            }
        });

        return(
            <Route {...rest} render={props => (
                loggedIn ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/signin" />
            )} 
            />
        )
    }

    export default PrivateRoute;
```

y en el publicRoute:

```
    // React
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    // React-router-dom
    import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

    const PublicRoute = ({component: Component, restricted, ...rest}) => {
        const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
        
        useEffect(() => {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            if(token !== null) {
                setLoggedIn(true);
            }
        });

        return(
            <Route {...rest} render={props => (
                (loggedIn && restricted) ? <Redirect to="/books/home" /> : <Component {...props}/>
            )}
            />
        );
    }

    export default PublicRoute;
```

Aparte de esto tengo el metodo signIn en donde setea el token en `local storage` y hace el push hacia la ruta `/books/home`.

```
signIn = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { store: { loginData, loggedIn } } = this.state;
    const { signinUser, history } = this.props;

    const variables = {
        email: loginData.email,
        password: loginData.password
    };
    
    try {
        const response = await signinUser({variables});
        
        if(response) {
          const { data: {signinUser:{token}} } = response;
          localStorage.setItem('token', token);
         /*  history.push('/books/home'); */
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Puede ser la configuración de tus hooks `useEffect`, hay que configurarlos para que corran solo una vez (skip effects), en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425132/paginas-dinámicas-en-nextjs/425335#425335) podrás ver la configuración de `useEffect` con skip effects, basta con especificar el array de dependencias vacío, dale un voto si fue de utilidad, saludos

Comment: Hola gracias por la pronta respuesta, pero no me ha funcionado. incluso intente cambiar de tipo de componente a uno de clase. igual presenta ese loop con la ruta en la url

Comment: Algo que he visto en muchos casos, es que los loops son provocados por `useEffect`,  voy a tratar de emular el error de mi lado, parece mas complicado de lo que pensamos.

Comment: Si está medio raro este bug, es como si de alguna forma verificará token y seteare la variable loggedIn a true y falso todo el tiempo

Comment: Intenté reproducir el error sin éxito, pero al despejar las banderas `loggedIn`,  pude darme cuenta que el problema puede estar en el `redirect`, en esta [publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489452/react-react-router-privateroute-infinite-loop) presentan un diseño muy parecido al que estas proponiendo, suerte.

Comment: Efectivamente cambie el redirect a un llamado de una funcion, como desimos aqui "si funciona no lo toques" jajaja gracias man!, lo deberia de poner en responder mi pregunta?

Comment: que bien que ya jaló, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se pudo llegar a una respuesta, que me permitio subsanar el problema de buena forma y esta solucion (gracias a la ayuda de @g.4) fue cambiar el `<Redirect to="">` en el condicional ternario para la condicion true por un callback a una funcion que redirecciona con el `Redirect`:

```
// React
import React , { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// React-router-dom
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {

const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(token !== null) {
        setLoggedIn(true);
    }
}, []);

const redirectToSignIn = () => {
    <Redirect to="/signin" />
}

return(
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        loggedIn ? <Component {...props} /> : redirectToSignIn()
     )} 
    />
)
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```